# Sinatra: Function to handle rendering of every route?

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra, output

I'm trying to work out Sintra's respond_with and respond_to, routes and whatnot. The doco does seem to talk about moving the code to some single point, but I can't work out how to do it.

I've got a series of routes that all return Json or XML with something like:

```
respond_with :index, data do |f|
  f.xml { XmlSimple.xml_out(data, {'XmlDeclaration' => true}) }
  f.on('application/json') { data.to_json }
end
```

The XmlSimple call might have some different options here and there. In one case, the route does its own XML rendering (because it's complicated). Going forward, I'd like to add in optional 'pretty' output, and maybe also add in some sort of HTML templated output.

What I'd like to do is have all of my routes either return a Hash or a string. If it's a string, then we can just pass that off to Sinatra to output as it normally would. If the route returns a hash, then it would be rendered in a similar manner to the above, depending on request or query string parameters.

My problem is: how can I configure some sort of 'defualt' output filter on the output of the routes?

Answer (score 1):

According to Sinatra documentation, "After filters are evaluated after each request within the same context and can also modify the request and response." So you could write a global after filter that processes that data differently depending on what class it is, or really any validation you want. Instance variables accessed in the routes can be used in the Before/After routes.

```
get '/foo' do
  data = some_data
end

after do
  data if data.class == String
  data.do_more_things if data.class == Hash
end
```

If that doesn't work, I believe you can simply write a method and call it on the data at the end of your route:

```
def format_for_response(data)
  data if data.class == String
  data.do_more_things if data.class == Hash
end

get '/foo' do
  format_for_response(data)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I couldn't get the 'after' filter to work - it seems that Sinatra barfs whenever a router returns anything other than a String, so the 'after' filter doesn't even get a look in.

The format_for_response() method seems like the only way - I was hoping to avoid it, instead using some "automatic" solution, but it looks like I'm out of luck.

Comment: The problem I've now got is that the format_for_response() method needs access to 'request', 'response', 'params' etc, and to hook into the templating system if it needs a template. I just stumbled over 'Sinatra Extentions' doco - it's a bit thin on details, but it may be a way to do this.

Comment: Whenever I need to access the request data from a POST, I always use the 'request.body' variable.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

With help from @sean-larkin, I've used a method inside a Sinatra Extension (http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html). The idea being that Helpers get access to 'params', 'request', 'response' etc, and so can do decision making about the output format required.

Here's an example rendering method (saved into lib/sinatra/render.rb) that outputs minified XML/JSON unless you specify "?pretty=true" in the query string of the request:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'xmlsimple'

module Sinatra
  module OutputRender
    module Helpers
      def render_output(data, xml_opts = {})
        if data.class == String
          # If it's already rendered, then just output it
          return data
        end
        pretty = (params['pretty'] && params['pretty'] == 'true') ? true : false
        respond_with :index, data do |f|
          f.on(:xml) { XmlSimple.xml_out(data, xml_opts) }
          f.on(:json) { pretty ? ::JSON.pretty_generate(data) : data.to_json }
        end
      end
    end
    def self.registered(app)
      app.helpers OutputRender::Helpers
    end
  end
  register OutputRender::Helpers
end
```

...and then in the files that have routes (eg. lib/banana.rb) I have this:

```
require "sinatra/base"
require "sinatra/render"
get '/banana', :provides => [:xml, :json] do
  x = Hash.new()
  x['one'] = two

  render_output x
end
```

So I'm left with a 'rendering function' which I was hoping to avoid, but it seems like a clean way to do what I'm after. I'm now going to add in HTML rendering of the data so that there's nice browser output if you're using a browser to hit up the routes, and work on making XML output always have a declaration, always be below a particular root node, etc.